# How to remove the field from where the condition in magento 2

Tags: magento2, magento-2.0, magento2.2.7

How to remove the field from where the condition in magento 2?

in error log : Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'show_in_custom_assistance' in 'where clause'.

```
$collection = $this->_autoSearchCollection->create();
    $collection->setVisibility($this->_catalogProductVisibility->getVisibleInCatalogIds());
    $collection->addAttributeToSelect('*')
    ->setStoreToFilter($storeid)
    ->addStoreFilter($storeid)
    ->addSearchFilter($search_arr)
    ->addMinimalPrice()
    ->addUrlRewrite()
    ->addTaxPercents();
    $collection->addCategoryFilter($category);
    // echo $collection->getSelect();

    return $collection;
```

I have tried the $collection->removeAttributeToSelect('show_in_custom_assistance');
 and $collection->removeFieldFromSelect('show_in_custom_assistance'); but didn't worked.

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution myself. Just make the attribute not searchable so that the attribute will not come in the search filter.